Automatic startup of applications on Windows Server is delayed
We have some shortcuts to applications and scripts on our Windows Server 2019 located in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup (Shell:Startup) but they start with delay when administrator logs in through RDP (which can be much later than the system boots up). How to fix this to have these apps and scripts started exactly when system boots up?
